# Why was my question about programming languages closed?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, specific-question

This is the question I've asked:

- [QML-like approaches or programming languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639780/qml-like-approaches-or-programming-languages)

It was closed by a guy who does not even program in either QML nor C++. I am observing compulsive closing of my questions recently, even though I am making the best effort in asking them.

Now, why were not similar questions about programming languages closed but mine was? Just yesterday another question of mine was closed by a guy programming in Java, without a single C++ post. That question was then later reopened. If you think the closing was justified, please explain why. The irony is, I wasn't even asking for a tool, necessarily, but an approach within a language would also be fine.

Here are some questions I think are similar to mine, but were not closed:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867656/starting-a-game-development-in-an-exotic-language-i-am-just-learning-lisp-hask
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436391/what-programming-language-to-choose
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300878/advice-on-languages-to-choose-beginner

Comment: Thanks for finding those 3 questions.  All 3 have 2 close votes now, so should be close sooner or later.

Comment: I don't see the close votes.

Comment: I think a real problem is that it's too broad. It's about programmers not about programming (*cough-programmers-se* *cough-migration*).

Comment: I'd also like to warn future posters, that apparently my closing and reopening voting rights on SO were revoked after posting this question to metastackoverflow. The kangaroo court also imposed sanctions.

Comment: Wut? You don't have 3k rep. You mean flagging?

Comment: @user1095108 your rights weren't revoked, you don't have the 3K rep necessary to vote to close posts that are not your own.  You can see close votes and vote to close/reopen your own posts once you get to 250, but everything else requires 3K

Comment: Don't know how, but it was possible, I could vote to reopen before. Maybe a bug.

Comment: On your own posts

Comment: All three of the listed questions should also be closed. Historically SO was more lenient on such questions but go stricter as they are distracting and dont encourage clean answers

Comment: @LukeMcGregor trying to close, just waiting for the close bug to get fixed.

Comment: If you're asking for other people's "experiences", that's **too broad** for [main].

Comment: @Cupcake and, yet again, I was not asking for experiences.

Comment: @user1095108 then you need to clarify your question to remove that.

Comment: @Cupcake I did, but you reverted.

Comment: @user1095108 fixed, sorry.

Comment: @Cupcake Thanks. Hopefully, a good Samaritan will now hit the reopen. Only one vote missing.

Comment: It still reads like a question asking for a recommendation, and recommendation questions should be closed

Comment: @JK. Resistance is futile. We shall close your question and others like it.

Comment: @user1095108 maybe try asking on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/)? Not trying to be mean, I'm serious. They have less-restrictive guidelines and moderation than [main]. Smart people have been known to frequent the site too, like people from GitHub and Basecamp.

Comment: @Cupcake I'll finish my QML-like language more likely and I'll ask questions on SO more sparingly.

Comment: @user, ask as many questions as you like on SO, just don't ask for programming language recommendations.... you've asked 92 questions and the vast majority look to be open. Having a question closed doesn't mean it's a bad question, it's just off-topic for SO. As were the other 3 (now closed) questions you linked.

Comment: @OGHaza The thing is, that I've quoted wikipedia on what kind of a programming language QML is. A language either is declarative, reactive, scripting, or it is not. It is not open to opinion.

Answer (score 5):

The problem really is that your question is really a discussion. Discussions are off topic on stack overflow. You might have more luck asking such a question on Programmers as they have a bit looser mandate.

I agree with andrew in that this is a recommendation based question as the following statement is asking for recommendations:

> Do there exist programming languages or approaches within a language
>   (such as within C++), that mimick QML? That is, you've had a similar
>   (positive) experience using them, as you've had with QML?

Comment: @user1095108 i think i actually said a pretty similar thing to stijn, however if you want the question reopened on SO you will need to phrase it as a clear problem statement which will attract well defined answers. This means producing an example of what you have tried (perhaps the closest thing to have found to QML) and a problem that you have with that example that can attract well defined answers (such as if you did this you would get what you want) Dont phrase it like you want a different tool simply that you are open to a solution that might involve one

Comment: The thing is, I am reimplementing QML, compiling my language into lua, but it is very hard work. I'd like to know if something else exists. From what I read, it is illegal to ask such a question on SO anyway. It is not really asking for recommendations, anything remotely similar to QML would do.

Comment: @user1095108 perhaps SO isnt the right place for this then, SE is really not the right tool to find recommendations but you may have more luck on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've reworded my question. But, if you think it appropriate, move it over to Programmers, please. I've made the best effort in asking, that I could.

Answer (score 3):

Similar questions that aren't closed should not be used as an argument. It either means those questions weren't closed yet or those questions are not quite as similar as you think.

It doesn't matter that the person who closed your question doesn't know QML or C++, it's unnecessary for the reason it was closed:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Let's take a look at the question you're asking:

> Do there exist programming languages or approaches within a language (such as within C++), that mimick QML? That is, you've had a similar (positive) experience using them, as you've had with QML?

You're asking SO to recommend a programming language, which is off-topic with the reason your question was closed.

The second part of your question, asking for experiences, could either fall under the *primarily opinion-based* close reason or the *too broad* reason. We can only use one close reason though, so one was picked.

Comment: Your explanation is unsatisfactory, for one, I did not ask for a tool, site or resource. Neither a recommendation. I've asked what exists out there.

Comment: @user1095108 I've added a bit to my answer. Asking what exists out there is asking for a recommendation.

Comment: Either I'm illiterate or I wasn't asking about experiences. Your answer reads to me, tough luck, you can't do anything about a tyrannical moderator. A kangaroo court will always rule in his favor.

Comment: Yeah. This answer totally goes against the whole... "community" part of "community moderation". And you replaced it with "Too bad, you must be wrong and reopening totally isn't a thing".

Comment: @user1095108 That's not what I'm saying at all. I would have closed your question too. And it's a copy pasted quote from your question, perhaps I'm illiterate then? How should I interpret "you've had a similar (positive) experience with them"?

Comment: @user1095108, you must slap the proverbial face of the mod in question, and best him in the battle-arena of [Codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered).

Comment: @Stijn I am glad to explain. I was asking for a _programming language,_ with which someone had had a positive experience, similar to the one he had had with `QML`.

Comment: @user1095108 That looks like you're asking for someone to recommend you a programming language.

Comment: @Stijn Please suggest how I might reword my question, or transfer it over to Programmers please.

Comment: @user1095108 I'm not familiar enough with Programmers to vote for a migration, but perhaps others will make that vote. Can I suggest that in the future you try to have a little more respect for those who try to help you? Your comments on my answer and on the other answer left a bad taste with me.

Comment: @user1095108 there is no  migration path to programmers.se, you should do that your self by reposting there. Your demanding tone might be normal to you but please remember that this can easily be misinterpreted by other members of this community.